# Jest test - how to give enter after input to make as chip component entry in typescript

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I am using a multiselect form control element which stores multiple input as chip components.
For that user need to type text and click enter button. Then the user typed input as chip value.

In UI, its working fine.
But in jest, I am not able to add it as chip component. How to give enter key in Jest

```
<FormControl>
      <div className="relative">
        <div className="flex flex-row">
          <div className="flex items-center gap-2 w-[560px] flex-wrap flex-row border-2 border-lightgray p-4 rounded-4">
            {formInputNames.map((item, index) => (
              <Chip key={index} size="small" onDelete={() => handleDelete(item, index)} label={item} />
            ))}

            <Input
              value={currentFormInput}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onKeyDown={handleKeyUp}
              disableUnderline
              placeholder={placeholder}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="flex ml-[-3rem]">
            {formInputNames.length > 0 && (
              <ClearIcon onClick={handleClearAll} className="cursor-pointer fixed self-center" />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <FormHelperText style={{ color: 'red' }}>{helperText}</FormHelperText>
        <FormHelperText>{error}</FormHelperText>
      </div>
    </FormControl>
  )
```

I am trying to write Jest test for this component.

fireEvent.change(screen.getByPlaceholderText(currentFormNamePlaceholder), { target: { value: testcurrentForm } })
fireEvent.keyDown(screen.getByPlaceholderText(currentFormNamePlaceholder), { key: 'Enter' })

```
But Jest test is failing at this step. If any 1 input is given, add button is enabled in UI.

Jest test says add button is still disabled. 
while screen.debug(document.body, Infinity), I am seeing the input value alone.
not sure chip component is added or not. If added properly, add button will enabled.
```